# Is it possible to link a Tier-1 gateway with an Edge Cluster using the VMwareNSX-T API endpoint?

Tags: vmware

While it's feasible to establish an association between a **Tier-1 gateway** and an **Edge Cluster** through the VMWare NSX-T UI, is this association achievable by utilizing the NSX-T API endpoint?

I attempted to link a Tier-0 gateway to a specific Edge cluster using the API by including `edge_cluster_path` as an attribute during Tier-0 Gateway creation. However, I encountered an error message stating `"Json de-serialization error: property edge_cluster_path is unrecognized."` My goal is to achieve this association through the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to link Tier-1 gateway with edgecluster. To achive this you need to link Tier1 with localservices

here is example in java with useage:

```
LocaleServices edgeCLusterService = new LocaleServices();

edgeCLusterService.setResourceType("LocaleServices");
edgeCLusterService.setParentPath(tier1Created.getParentPath());
edgeCLusterService.setPath(tier1Created.getPath()+"/locale-services/default");
edgeCLusterService.setMarkedForDelete(false);
edgeCLusterService.setOverridden(false);
edgeCLusterService.setEdgeClusterPath("yourEdgeClusterPath");

this.localeServicesService.update(tier1Created.getId(), UUID.randomUUID().toString(),edgeCLusterService);
```